# include field from another class

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have a class called `Program` that has a field called `ProgramStatusCode`.  I'm planning to create another class called `Status` that has the `StatusCode (ID)` and `StatusDescription`.  The Status class has a column called `StatusType` that needs to be filtered on `Program` and an `Active` column that needs to be filtered on `Yes`.

How do I add StatusDescription to the `Program` class that's already filtered on `Program` and `Yes`?

Here are the classes:

Program.cs

```
public class Program
{
    public decimal ID { get; set; }
    public string ProgramName { get; set; }
    public string ProgramDescription { get; set; }
    public string ProgramStatusCode { get; set; }
}
```

Status.cs

```
public class Status
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string StatusType { get; set; }
    public string StatusDescription { get; set; }
    public string Active { get; set; }
}
```

**Update**
The work around that I'm doing is creating another class called ProgramFinal with a field called Status.  Instead of creating another class just to include Status, I'd like to have Status in the Program class.

Here is the code:

ProgramFinal.cs

```
public class ProgramFinal
{
    public decimal ID { get; set; }
    public string ProgramName { get; set; }
    public string ProgramDescription { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
}
```

Linq Query:

```
programFinal = (from program in dbContext.Program
                join status in dbContext.Status on program.ProgramStatusCode equals status.ID
                where status.Active.Contains("Y") && status.StatusType.Contains("Program") && program.ProgramName.Contains(programName)
                select new ProgramFinal
                {
                    ID = program.ID,
                    ProgramName = program.ProgramName,
                    ProgramDescription = program.ProgramDescription,
                    Status = status.StatusDescription
                }).FirstOrDefault();
```

So instead of creating a new class just to get the Status Description, I'd like to have Status Description in the Program class itself.

Thanks!

Comment: Where is `StatusCd` in `Program` class? and `Status Code` in `Status` class?

Comment: ProgramStatusCode in Program and ID in Status

Comment: `Active column that needs to be filtered on 'Y'.` - What is `Y` here?

Comment: Y (Yes) indicates that Status is still Active.

Comment: Now tell clearly what are you expecting?

Comment: How do I add StatusDescription to the Program class that's already filtered on Program and Yes?  The edits weren't required to my original post.

Comment: Not clear to what you are actually wanting. Please add some code that you have already tried.

Comment: Without a foreign key, how do you know which statuscode belongs to which program?